# Don't allow full stops, commas etc in GridView Textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView were one of the columns is a textbox:

```
 <asp:GridView  style="width:75%;float:left"  
    ID="gvPieceOutturns" 
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"
    CssClass="tblResults" 
    runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvPieceOutturns_ItemDataBound"                          
    DataKeyField="ID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    allowpaging="false"" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="MemComment">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMemComment" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to add some validation to the textbox to prevent the user from entering full stops, commas etc. Only allow letters and numbers.

I have a function that gets called when the user tabs off the textbox:

```
protected void UpdateMemOutturnComment(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Comment = hfMemOutturnComment.Value;
}
```

But how do I alert the user if they enter an invalid character?
Is there a way to alert the user as soon as an invalid character is entered or do I need to wait until they have finished filling in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RegularExpressionValidator for standard validation, and call the `onkeypress` event of the TextBox for immediate validation with an alert message:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="MemComment" ItemStyle-CssClass="memComment">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMemComment" runat="server" onkeypress="ValidateMemComment(event);" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revMemComment" runat="server" CssClass="validatorMemComment" ControlToValidate="txtMemComment" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Invalid character" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The following CSS style class prevents line breaks between the TextBox and the validator in the cell:

```
.memComment
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The `onkeypress` event handler in client code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateMemComment(event) {
        var code = event.which || event.keyCode;
        var isNumeric = (48 <= code && code <= 57);
        var isUpperAlpha = (65 <= code && code <= 90);
        var isLowerAlpha = (97 <= code && code <= 122);
        if (!isNumeric && !isUpperAlpha && !isLowerAlpha) {
            setTimeout(function () { alert("Invalid character!"); }, 0);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `setTimeout` function is used to allow the character to be displayed before showing the alert message.

Comment: that's great thanks. The Invalid message appears under the textbox but how would I get it to display as an alert message?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please note that I added `ItemStyle-CssClass="memComment"` to the TemplateField, and `Display="Dynamic"` to the validator (which you can change to `Static` if you prefer).

Comment: your updated answer still doesn't display the message as an alert. I don't see any difference adding `Display="Dynamic` or `Display="Static`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread your previous comment. I will post an update as soon as possible.

Comment: I modified the key detection (using `onkeypress` instead of `onkeyup`). The Javascript code now doesn't use the validator at all. Since the validator always checked the full text, it showed the alert message when trying to remove successive invalid characters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to recommend you look into [ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx#Anchor_9).  They allow you to validate input based on a regular expression.  If the input does not match, it alerts the user and does not allow submission.  I believe it fires when the user leaves the field.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Only Numbers and letters are allowed" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
```

In case you aren't familiar with regex, it will only match strings that contain lowercase and uppercase letters, and numbers